# How do i get the price?

Tags: percentages

The price for the product was raised by 22% and amounted to 2013 dollars. What was the price of the product before the price was raised ?

please guys i would like explaining and steps for the solution thank you :)

Comment: $122 = 2 \cdot 61 \; \; ;$ $\; \; 2013 = 3 \cdot 11 \cdot 61$

Comment: can you explained for me please

Comment: your answer is $2013 / 1.22$

Comment: how 22% be 1.22 ?

Comment: An experiment, different question: if you began with 1000 dollars and raised it by 22% what would it become?

Comment: sorry buddy didn't get that first time , thanks for the heads up :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you raise a price by $22\%$ you multiply it by $1+\frac {22}{100}=1.22$  To recover  the original you divide the new one by $1.22$

Comment: thanks mate , you just put my finger on the spot